# SQRC use to verify e-delivered certificate

Tags: authentication, certificates, qr-code

I have a need to provide a means of validating a certificate that is e-delivered.

My thought is to use an [SQRC](https://www.denso-wave.com/en/system/qr/fundamental/qrcode/sqrc/index.html) to enable that verification by linking to a secure site that contains the original certificate and display that to enable verification of the e-delivered certificate.

Seems straight forward, but, I wonder about any security issues with this use, including the ability of a rogue actor gaining access to the secure site that is used to verify the e-delivered and printed certificate.

It's probably obvious that I do not have in depth knowledge of SQRC. While this application seems straight forward at first glance, are there other issues that could impede such a use?

Comment: Please provide references for non-standard terms.

Comment: My apologies, what do you consider non-standard terms in my post?

Comment: Sqrc is not a common term that people would know. I had to look it up and insert a link for others.

Comment: Again, my apologies. I've been researching QR code uses where it popped up. I'll be more sensitive in the future.